# How can I add opacity functionality to my Drawing App?

Tags: android, paint, draw, opacity

What I have for now is this :

[image]

It is as simple as you may see already. It just has four buttons on the top of the screen: new drawing screen, paint brush, erase brush and save the drawing. And on the bottom of the screen there are colors for the actual brush(paint). 
What I want to do(and what would be awesome practise for me) is I want to add one more button maybe at the top of the screen which should let the user to draw with a smaller opacity option, I mean I want that when the user taps the button it lets him to choose what opacity he wants to draw(maybe use SeekBar for selection, or maybe without Seekbar, just use constant for the value of opacity) and let the brush use that. 
It would be awesome if someone would take to the tutorial or maybe Android Reference for similar functionality, because I can't find similar to this in Google. Thank you very much for any help.

P.S. Sorry for my English grammar mistakes in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in this sample

[Android Drawing With Opacity](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-drawing-with-opacity/?search_index=6)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `setAlpha` property for paint object in onDraw Method